# Call self-executing function from method/module

Tags: javascript, methods, anonymous-function

Let's say I have a function made up of private and public methods, like this:

```
(function () {
    var private_var = "hey";
    function private_function () {
        // stuff
    }
    stuff = {
        public_var: "hey",
        public_function: function () {
            // this can be called from the outside with no prob.
        },
        do_this_now_and_later: (function dothis() {
            // i could call this from the namespace "dothis()"
            // but not the method name, stuff.do_this_now_and_later()
        })()
    }
})(window.load = window.load || {});
```

i want to execute the function `do_this_now_and_later()` as soon as it's rendered, but again later as well.

if i wrote this example code correctly, one should be able to call that function by the namespace `dothis()`, but is it possible to call that function by its method?

Comment: only if you "return dothis;" at the end of dothis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return dothis() in your function.

```
(function () {
var private_var = "hey";
function private_function () {
    // stuff
}
stuff = {
    public_var: "hey",
    public_function: function () {
        // this can be called from the outside with no prob.
    },
    do_this_now_and_later: (function dothis(v) {
        alert(v);
        return dothis;
        // i could call this from the namespace "dothis()"
        // but not the method name, stuff.do_this_now_and_later()
    })('foo')
}

stuff.do_this_now_and_later('bar');
})(window.load = window.load || {});
```